# Alogical Defining Functions Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure how to create a function that takes as input a number and returns the minimum number of times that the number  needs to be divided by 2 in order to get a number equal or smaller than 1??

So far this what I have done:

```
def alogical(n):
   min_times= n//2
   return round(min_times)
```

Comment: `import math; alogical = lambda x: math.ceil(math.log(x,2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def alogical(n, count=0):
    return n <= 1 and count or alogical(n / 2, count + 1)
```

I'm using logical shortcutting as a substitute for if/branching statements.  Sorta bending the rules.

> This doesn't work for the case that n = 1. The result should be 0 but
>   it gives 1. – Tagc

Fine:

```
def alogical(n):
    def inner_alogical(n, count=1):
        return n <= 1 and count or inner_alogical(n / 2, count + 1)

    return inner_alogical(n) - 1
```

Happy now?  ;-)

Comment: This doesn't work for the case that n = 1. The result should be 0 but it gives 1.

Comment: How about `return count if n <= 1 else alogical(n / 2, count + 1)`? Gives `f(1)=0`, `f(1.1)=1`, `f(5.4)=3`.

Comment: @Tagc, thanks for catching that.  Your proposed solution violates rules echoed by the OP, "may not use loops nor if/branching".  I believe I've come up with a workaround -- not pretty but consistent with my original.

Comment: *"Your proposed solution violates rules echoed by the OP, "may not use loops nor **if**/branching"."* That's true, I noticed after I posted. But doesn't your original solution violate that rule anyway, since it relies on short-circuiting behaviour which essentially means it has branching logic? TBF I think @cwallenpoole nailed it, but I upvoted your solution all the same.